# Cannot update mongoose attribute with .update()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have created a register system for my site that sends a confirmation email to the user who signed up, with their confirmation code being the `_id` of their account in the mongoose database.

Then, back on my site, they enter their confirmation code, and I want to use an `.update()` method to change the value of the `confirmed` attribute from **`0`** to **`1`** in the database for that user.

Here is my code:

```
router.post('/confirmAcc',function(req, res, next) {

  var getid=req.body.confirmcode;
  console.log(getid);
  var requis = { "_id": getid };

  User.update(requis, {confirmed: '1'}, function (err, doc){
    console.log(doc);
    if (err) throw err;
  });

  res.render('index', {title:'nDoto'});
});
```

The database has no problem matching the `id`, but it doesn't update the existing "`confirmed`" attribute to "**`1`**".

I am not sure why.

Also, when I run the code, and put in my confirmation code and that function runs, the console writes:

> `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`

Comment: Are you saying that if you replace the update with a find in the above code, you get back a record?

Comment: Well actually your comment just fixed my problem. I decided to not use update, and I just used findOne(). I then used `doc.credentials.confirmed="1"`, and it updated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Instead of using User.update(), I used:

```
router.post('/confirmAcc',function(req, res, next) {
var getid=req.body.confirmcode;

var requis = { "_id": getid };

User.findOne(requis, function (err, doc){
    doc.credentials.confirmed="1";
    doc.save();
    if (err) throw err;
});
res.render('index', {title:'nDoto'});
});
```

And this worked :)

Comment: Be aware that it will load the object (Client side). Update does not load the object, which could avoid a lack of perfomance if the object is big.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help but I wanted to say that the update method has a $set operator [$set documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/).. The $set operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value. So if you still wanted to use update() maybe something like this would of worked:

`db.catalog.update({"_id" : getid},{$set : {"confirmed" : "1"}})`

**This should change the "confirmed" field's value.**

Comment: That would work as well. I now realize it initially didn't work because confirmed was not in quotes. Thank you for your example!